# Using circle as polygon for querying PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, postgis-2.0, php

I'm trying to query PostGIS and find some object features that intersect with a circular buffer created by the user using OpenLayers, JavaScript and PHP.

I use the following code for creating the circle:

```
var circle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(X, Y),
    1,
    30
);
```

and then I'm planning to use the following SELECT Query in my php code:

```
SELECT b.geom
FROM buildings AS b
WHERE ST_WITHIN (b.geom, ST_MAKEPOLYGON(circle, srid));
```

Q1: how can I pass the geometry created for the circle from my .JS file to .php file? can I pass it as an object? can I do something like below??:

```
http://mydomain.com/page.php?buffer=circle
```

Q2: Is my SELECT query correct? Am I using the correct function ST_MAKEPOLYGON?

Answer (score 7):

Since your search region is circular, it is perhaps best not to consider it to be a polygon, but as a *point with a radius* and to use the [`ST_DWithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) function:

> ST_DWithin — Returns true if the geometries are within the specified distance of one another.

It should save you and the processor a lot of effort.